# ROR, Redis, Resque, God & Cron on Ubuntu Server - Boot

Tags: ruby-on-rails, redis, cron, boot, god

I have made several jobs that god takes care of in my ruby application. However when the server reboots the job stops. I want to avoid this so I've made this script on my server. It looks like this.

**my_app.sh**

```
#!/bin/bash

# god tasks

#


case $1 in

start)

/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/bin/god      
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/bin/god start
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/bin/god load /usr/local/Linux/apache2/www/hej.se/ruby/config/resque.god
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/bin/god load /usr/local/Linux/apache2/www/hej.se/ruby/config/resque_schedule.god

;;
esac

exit 0
```

If I log in manually and write

> "/etc/init.d/my_app start"

it gives me

```
Sending 'start' command

No matching task or group
Sending 'load' command with action 'leave'

The following tasks were affected:
  resque-0
  resque-1
  resque-2
  resque-3
  resque-4
Sending 'load' command with action 'leave'

The following tasks were affected:
  resque_scheduler
```

And everything works, it does what I want it to do, i.e the jobs.

I have tried several ways to start this script on boot (Linux 10.4.4 LTS), rc.local, rc-default and now my latest attempt is crontab.

The script must be run under my user and not root, (it can't find the ruby installation if I run it under root).

Because of this I've configured the crontab under my user account:

```
@reboot /etc/init.d/my_app start
```

Sadly this doesn't work... I don't what I'm doing wrong. And this should probably not be necessary. I mean shouldn't you be able to this per auto when booting up the ruby application?

Im using passenger on this server, I don't know if this has something to do with it?

**The solution below with the changes I made to the sh:**

my_app.sh

```
bash -c "source /usr/local/rvm/scripts/rvm && /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/bin/god"      
bash -c "source /usr/local/rvm/scripts/rvm && /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/bin/god start"
bash -c "source /usr/local/rvm/scripts/rvm && /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/bin/god load /usr/local/Linux/apache2/www/hej.se/ruby/config/resque.god"
bash -c "source /usr/local/rvm/scripts/rvm && /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/bin/god load /usr/local/Linux/apache2/www/hej.se/ruby/config/resque_schedule.god"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Forget the cronjob.

Centos/Fedora:

```
sudo chmod a+x /etc/init.d/my_app
sudo chkconfig --add my_app
sudo chkconfig my_app on
```

Ubuntu/Debian:

```
sudo update-rc.d my_app defaults
```

Both of these symlink the script to `/etc/rc1.d`, `/etc/rc2.d`, etc., and make the script available to run on boot for those runlevels.

Comment: How do I make the script run on boot? It can't find ruby when trying to run it under boot...

"/usr/bin/env: ruby: No such file or directory"

Comment: The commands I described above will add it to the boot process. Check in /etc/rc*.d and those are all the scripts that automatically get run (their `start` command) for that runlevel (0-6).

Comment: If your ruby can't be found then you just need to figure out the paths. RVM tends to mess with that stuff and I generally don't recommend it on a production server, but since you already have it installed, you'll just need to figure out how to configure it to find ruby properly.

Comment: That was the trick! Wohoo! Thanks a bunch :)

I edited my q with the solution.